# Binding to UserControl in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a UserControl...

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Name="ClientsListControl" ....... >
<Grid>
    <ListBox Margin="10" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
             Name="profilesListBox" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ClientsListControl, Path=Items}" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class ClientsList : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ClientsListViewModel), typeof(ClientsList));

    public ClientsListViewModel Items
    {
        get
        {
            return (ClientsListViewModel) GetValue(ItemsProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public ListBox ListBox
    {
        get
        {
            return profilesListBox;
        }
    }

    public ClientViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return (ClientViewModel) profilesListBox.SelectedItem;
        }
    }

    public ClientsList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

... and Window.

The problem is:

1) this works:

```
<cm:ClientsList x:Name="clientsList" Items="{Binding}" />
<TextBox Width="100" Height="20" Name="Bla" Text="{Binding ElementName=clientsList, Path=ListBox.SelectedItem.Name}" />
```

2) this doesn't work:

```
<cm:ClientsList x:Name="clientsList" Items="{Binding}" />
<TextBox Width="100" Height="20" Name="Bla" Text="{Binding ElementName=clientsList, Path=SelectedItem.Name}" />
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Since SelectedItem is a property of ListBox the first code is 100% valid. Since you found a solution for your initial problem, what's wrong with code no. 1 so that you'd prefer no. 2 over it?

Comment: first code works correctly. the second causes no reaction on the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `SelectedItem` a dependency property and bind the `SelectedItem` property of the ListBox to it just like you did with `Items`.

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox Margin="10" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
             Name="profilesListBox" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ClientsListControl, Path=Items}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=ClientsListControl, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public static DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(ClientViewModel), typeof(ClientsList));

public ClientViewModel SelectedItem
{
    get { return (ClientViewModel)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
}
```